# Bootgrid ajax setting in data-api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-bootgrid

The documentation of the [BootGrid](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Documentation) says that for setting the http method to GET or for setting the ajax to true I need to use the `method` and the `ajax` (in javascript) but the Data-API example shows the attributes `data-url` and `data-ajax` so I figure I need to use `data-method` as well, and cannot use `ajax` as an attribute name without the `data-...` (namespace?).

Correct?

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with the JQuery ajax api?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

Anywhere this is explained?

Answer (score 0):

Since posting this question I've found that, yes, you must add the data- for the data api, and not use the data- prefix when using the javascript.